# How to replace people.me from Google+ with Google People/Google Sign In api?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-plus

I had a "sign in with Google+" function in my web-app. Upon signing in I would show user's email and name on the page and save it to database. To fetch user's profile data after sign in I used Google+ API method `people.me` with `access_token` in GET params.

Google+ API is going to shut down on March 7. I have to migrate to Google People or some other api. How do I achieve the same goal with a different google API? I need to fetch email and name by known auth token.

Comment: Basically, instead of accessing `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` you access `https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me`. The data structure is a little different, but not by much. Exact implementation depends on the library or code you're using; if you're using a library you may just need to update it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I get 404 by that url with a message: `The requested URL /userinfo/v2/me was not found on this server`. Something is off. It does not look like People API. Which API is it?

Comment: I don't get a 404. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect

Comment: Can you show the code you're currently using to get the profile?

Comment: @ceejayoz It works. I made some silly mistake. However I get email but not first name and last name of user.

Comment: @ceejayoz Your link will return all needed data if scope `profile` is also specified. I will accept your answer if you post it and mention scope. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use this through Laravel's Socialite, and they're replacing it with:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me
```

You may want the `profile` scope as part of the OAuth flow to make the profile data accessible through this methods. Otherwise it will return incomplete data.